# Trouble activating free SSL from Domain.com when using Hostinger as a web host

Tags: domains, web-hosting, https, security-certificate

Recently, I transfered my domain from GoDaddy to Domain.com. My hosting is still provide by Hostinger.com. Domain.com have an option of `Free SSL`. You just enabled it to get `SSL Certificate` and you don't have pay for it. To enable it, my nameservers should point to `ns1.domain.com` and `ns2.domain.com` along with my `A Record` (which I don't know what that is).

On domain.com, my nameservers are like (I had ns1-2.hostinger.com but I deleted them)

```
ns1.domain.com
ns2.domain.com
ns3.hostinger.com
ns4.hostinger.com
```

and my DNS Record have `@` and `ftp` A records along with hostinger IP's. But now, I can't reach out my site :D It says *This site is under development* on the title with blank page. I tried to change many nameserver and A record both on domain.com and hostinger.com.

Even if I can access to my website, I couldn't get SSL Certificate. How can I get that?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! It sounds like your site is not set up for SSL on port 443. You will need to check this and configure your site. You should be calling your web host for assistance. Cheers!!

Comment: You can not mix and match nameservers and hope it will work. You first need to define if you want your registrar or your webhoster to be your DNS provider and then use its nameservers and only his. Any setup can be achieved by any of the two choices but it also depends on other constraints. In any case you need to choose between both and use only one.

Comment: But my nameservers shouldn't include my hosting nameservers? In order to connect them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `NS` records to connect your domain name registrar to your DNS host.  You use `A` and `CNAME` records to at your DNS host to connect your domain name to the IP address of your web host.

You could have:

```
Domain.com -> NS ns1.hostinger.com -> A 1.1.1.1
```

Or you could have:

```
Domain.com -> NS ns1.domain.com -> A 1.1.1.1
```

In this case both your domain registrar and your web host offer DNS hosting services.    You can choose to use either.

According to [domain.com documentation](https://ijn.tl/p7QRW9) their free security certificates are based on 
[Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).  Lets encrypt works like:

1. You run the Lets Encrypt client to secure a domain name
2. The client contacts Lets Encrypt servers and requests a security certificate
3. The Lets Encrypt server asks for verification that you control the domain.  It gives you a token to publish.  There are variants for publishing it in a known location on your site, or in your DNS records.
4. The Lets Encrypt client puts the token in place and lets the server know.
5. The Lets Encrypt server verifies that the token has been publicly published and issues a security certificate for the domain
6. The Lets Encrypt client installs the certificate in your web server.

Because domain.com is not your web host, that last step is not going to be automatic.  That is a problem because the Lets Encrypt certificates expire every three months.  Any process that requires manual steps is going to a burden and will likely get neglected at some point.

[Hostinger will let you install a certificate from Lets Encrypt on their servers](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/ssl/how-to-install-free-ssl-from-lets-encypt-on-shared-hosting) and you might even be able to automate the process, but it sounds like a bit of scripting to make it happen.

All this is to say that getting a security certificate for your domain is not as easy with your setup as you were hoping.   It sounds like if you were hosting with domain.com, they could install and update the certificate for you.  However, with third party hosting it is going to be much harder.  It is certainly not going to work to just point DNS to domain.com.

Hostinger has a $12 "cheap lifetime SSL" option.  My guess is that is just an up-front fee for having them set up LetsEncrypt for you and keep the certificate updated.  Many web hosting companies will do the work of installing and updated LetsEncrypt certificates as part of your hosting plan.   $12 isn't an unreasonable fee, but it something that is more usually included in hosting plans in my experience.

Comment: First of all, thanks for answer. I have 3 questions. First, If I buy Hostinger's "cheap lifetime SSL", will it be mine even I decided to transfer my hosting to another web hosting company? Second, If I transfer my hosting to let's say domain.com (to where my domain is), will "the free" Lets Encrypt certificate meet my needs? Third, is it better to have both domain and hosting on the same company?

Comment: I don't know if it will be yours if you use a different host, but probably not.  It sounds like it is a fee for setting it up and keeping it updated on their servers.    Lets Encrypt powers [more than half of websites that have SSL](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/8d3vwz/lets_encrypt_passes_50_market_share/) so it meets most needs.  I use it myself.  I recommend separating out registration from hosting.   Hosting companies usually don't have good registration prices and registration companies don't have good hosting prices or offer lousy performance and service.

Comment: So do you think is it good for using domain.com for registration and hostinger for hosting?

Comment: I can't endorse either of them because I've never used them.  I'd look into to finding a web host that easily does LetsEncrypt if you don't want to pay the $12.   I don't know whether or not domain.com is a good option.  You should read reviews and decide for yourself.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time :)